# Create weave pattern

Tags: html, css

Inspired by the design of a [loop loom](https://stitchedmodern.com/cdn/shop/products/harrissville-traditional-potholder-weaving-loom-1_2048x.jpg) I am trying to make a pattern with html & css which will weave rows and columns inbetween eachother. My first attempt to accomplish this is to use css grid to place rows and columns, then relative positioning alongside z-index to choose which rows are above and below which columns. It works well for a single column, however once a second is added, there is no valid z-index for the column to not conflict with the first.

Here is a small example / mwe of my attempt.

```css
html {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 
    repeat(7, 1fr) /
    repeat(7, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
}

.row, .col {
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 9in;
  position: relative;
  border: 10px solid;
}

.row {
  border-color: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}

.row:nth-of-type(odd) {
  z-index: 1;
}

.row:nth-of-type(even) {
  z-index: 3;
}

.row:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.row:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-row-start: 3;
}

.row:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.row:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-row-start: 5;
}

.row:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-row-start: 6;
}

.col {
  border-color: tan;
  grid-row: 1 / 8;
  grid-column-end: span 1;
}

.col:nth-of-type(odd) {
  z-index: 2;
}

.col:nth-of-type(even) {
  /* no valid z-index to create pattern */
  /* z-index: ?????; */
  border-color: red;
}

.col:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.col:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}

.col:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column-start: 4;
}

.col:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column-start: 5;
}

.col:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-column-start: 6;
}

:is(.col, .row):hover {
  border-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<span class="col"></span>
<span class="col"></span>
<span class="col"></span>
<span class="col"></span>
<span class="col"></span>
```

I intend to incorporate the design into a simple react app which will allow dynamic control of rows/cols and changing colors, using it for visualizing different patterns before committing.

How can I create the weave / loop loom pattern in html & css?

Comment: This won't be possible with `z-index` and 1 element per "thread", you'll need to break the thread into multiple sections to achieve the "weave" effect. It could also be achieved but other methods, e.g. a `canvas` element.

Comment: @DBS I'm more than open to canvas options, any pointers/resources you have for getting started? I did think about breaking things into cells with replicas of the whole element but different z-index's and overflow hidden to try and replicate things, but I don't know if there might be a better way.

Comment: Is this just to make a pattern, ie you don’t need to have each square as an individual element for any other reason?

Comment: https://css-pattern.com/#g17

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make a mix of `z-index` and `clip-path`. z-index on its own cannot do this, nor transform 3D

Here is an example:

```css
html {
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
  min-height:100vh;
}

body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template: 
    repeat(7, 1fr) /
    repeat(7, 1fr);
  gap: 5px;
  width:50vmin;
  aspect-ratio:1;
}

.row, .col {
  padding: 2px;
  border-radius: 9in;
  position: relative;
}

.row {
  background: lightblue;
  grid-column: 1 / 8;
  grid-row-end: span 1;
}


.row:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-row-start: 2;
}

.row:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-row-start: 3;
}

.row:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-row-start: 4;
}

.row:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-row-start: 5;
}

.row:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-row-start: 6;
}

.col {
  background: tan;
  grid-row: 1 / 8;
  grid-column-end: span 1;
}

.col:nth-of-type(even) {
  background: red;
}

.col:nth-of-type(1) {
  grid-column-start: 2;
}

.col:nth-of-type(2) {
  grid-column-start: 3;
}

.col:nth-of-type(3) {
  grid-column-start: 4;
}

.col:nth-of-type(4) {
  grid-column-start: 5;
}

.col:nth-of-type(5) {
  grid-column-start: 6;
}

:is(.col, .row):hover {
  border-color: green;
}

body > :nth-child(odd) {
  z-index:2
}

body>:nth-child(7),
body>:nth-child(9) {
  clip-path: polygon(0% 0%, 0% 29%, 100% 29%, 100% 42%, 0% 42%, 0% 58%, 100% 58%, 100% 71%, 0% 71%, 0% 100%, 100% 100%, 100% 0%);
}
```

```html
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<div class="row"></div>
<span class="col"></span>
<span class="col"></span>
<span class="col"></span>
<span class="col"></span>
<span class="col"></span>
```

here is a generator for clip-path of a great help to start a pattern https://bennettfeely.com/clippy/ (note that the path can be applied to shape-outside , but that is for another purpose )

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to have the pattern as background images.

This snippet sets the warp up as vertical stripes as background to the container's before pseudo element using to right linear-gradients.

This gives this sort of pattern:

[image]

Then we add the wefts one line each as background to the after pseudo element. This time they are 50% the required color and 50% transparent, which allows the warp to show.

I've added a bit of JavaScript to create the CSS - just alter the width of the container to be whatever you want and set up the warp and weft colors as arrays.

```js
const weave = document.querySelector('.weave');
const warpColors = ['cyan', 'magenta', 'yellow'];
const weftColors = ['red', 'green', 'blue', 'orange'];

const wpn = warpColors.length;
const wfn = weftColors.length;

weave.style.setProperty('--wpn', wpn);
weave.style.setProperty('--wfn', wfn);

let warpBackgroundImage = '';
let weftBackgroundImage = '';
let weftBackgroundPositionY = '';

// go through building up the warps
for (let i = 0; i < wpn; i++) {
  warpBackgroundImage += ', ' + warpColors[i] + ' calc(' + i + ' * var(--s)) calc(' + (i + 1) + ' * var(--s))';
}
weave.style.setProperty('--wpbg', 'linear-gradient(to right' + warpBackgroundImage + ')');

// go through building up the wefts
for (let i = 0; i < wfn; i++) {
  weftBackgroundImage += ((i == 0) ? '' : ', ') + 'linear-gradient(to right, ' + ((i % 2 == 0) ? ('transparent 50%, ' + weftColors[i] + ' 50%)') : (weftColors[i] + ' 50%, transparent 50%)'));

  weftBackgroundPositionY += ((i == 0) ? '' : ',') + 'calc(' + i + '* var(--s))';
}
weave.style.setProperty('--wfbg', weftBackgroundImage);
weave.style.setProperty('--wfbgposy', weftBackgroundPositionY);
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
}

.weave {
  --w: 75vmin;
  width: var(--w);
  aspect-ratio: calc(var(--wpn) / var(--wfn));
  position: relative;
  /* size of square */
  --s: calc(var(--w) / var(--wpn));
}

.weave::before,
.weave::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}


/* the warp */

.weave::before {
  background-image: var(--wpbg);
}


/* the weft */

.weave::after {
  background-image: var(--wfbg);
  background-repeat: repeat no-repeat;
  background-size: calc(2 * var(--s)) var(--s);
  background-position-y: var(--wfbgposy);
}
```

```html
<div class="weave"></div>
```